# Разобрать json в php

Tags: json

Делаю

```
$jsons = json_decode($getid, true);
$idmid = $jsons->response[1]->items[id];
```

Получаю

```
jsons = {"response":{"count":129541,"items":[{"id":1111,"first_name":"Ксюша","last_name":"asd"}]}}
```

id = null.
Нужен id.

Answer (score 0):

```
$idmid = $jsons["response"]["items"]["id"];
```

Comment: все равно выводит NULL

Comment: можете сделать `var_dump( $jsons );` или `print_r( $jsons );` и дополнить что выдало в вашем посте?

Comment: array(1) { ["response"]=> array(2) { ["count"]=> int(129541) ["items"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> int(11111) ["first_name"]=> string(10) "Ксюша" ["last_name"]=> string(12) "фывфыв" } } } }

Comment: `$idmid = $jsons["response"]["items"][0]["id"];` попробуйте так

Comment: спасибо,  все ок

Answer (score 0):

Судя по json, итемов может быть несколько.
Поэтому Вам нужно получать не id, а список id:

```
$json = '{"response":{"count":129541,"items":[{"id":1111,"first_name":"Ксюша","last_name":"asd"}]}}';

$parsed = json_decode($json, true);

$ids = array_map(function($item) {
    return $item['id'];
}, $parsed['response']['items']);

var_dump($ids);
```

Ну или получать id только первого элемента: `$parsed['response']['items'][0]['id']`